# Opposite of hard to borrow?

Tags: options

If market participants are certain a stock will suffer a huge decline, the shares will become hard to borrow and an interest fee will be applied to borrow the stock. This interest fee eliminates the arbitrage opportunity from having ATM puts being more expensive than calls. In The context of options pricing, what happens when you have an opposite situation when everyone expects the stock to rise? If calls become more expensive than puts then you have arbitrage,  and there is no such thing as 'hard to buy' . I imagine what happens is the stock would suddenly spike higher until the easy money is made. Like what would happen if a billionaire pledged to keep the stock above a certain price level or if the company underwent extremely aggressive buybacks?

Comment: If "everyone" expects a stock to fall or rise, that will be reflected in the current price. Aggressive buybacks and billionaire pledges would also have an instantaneous effect (assuming you trusted the billionaire)